# Which letter would be hardest to avoid in an Esperanto lipogram?

Tags: spelling

A lipogram is a text where one or more letters have been omitted on purpose. A great example is French author George Perec’s novel *La disparition*, which doesn’t even once contain the letter E.

***In an Esperanto lipogram – which letter would be ”hardest” to avoid?*** The resulting text should still be fairly easy to understand – although a bit of quirkiness would be okay! :-) (Such as writing Esperant’ with an ellipsis, for example. Perec’s novel, which I read in an English translation [also without any E!], is certainly full of quirky rewordings…)

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but it might still interest you that Douglas R. Hofstadter in his book "Le ton beau de Marot" talks about this quite a lot and mentions various examples in different languages, although Esperanto does not come up. He calls E-less English "Anglo-Saxon" in a sort of iconic self-reference, and I thought E-less Esperanto could very nicely be Spranto.

Comment: That is interesting. I would have to check that book out. Spranto has a nice sound to it. If O is indeed the most ”inevitable” letter in the language, then maybe an alternative name would be Esperant’? Sprant’? :-)

Answer (score 5):

I guess it would have to be *s*, as it it used in any verb ending apart from the infinitive and the imperative. But *o* is also hard to avoid if you want to use any nominals.

Comment: Elision of the final O in nominals is allowed in poetic language – which would be okay in this context. :-) (Lipograms indeed can be seen as a kind of ”poetic prose” – with the lacking letter as a limitation, instead of, say, rhymes&rhythm…)

Comment: The first novel written entirely in the imperative tense without using nominals could be a notable achievement.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to go with **O** because without it you can't use future tense, plural nouns, or accusative nouns.

Tamen verki kelkajn frazojn kun manko de la litero "S" (krom tie ĉi) ne montru tiel grandan problemon. Jen ekzemplo.

Comment: It just struck me: Wouldn’t **I** be even harder to avoid? After all, you can write some phrases without plurals, and maybe avoid accusatives by passive rephrasings (”the cat was seen by the dog”). But how long could one keep writing without the table words, which all contain an i? (kiu, tie, kies, tiel ĉi etc.)

Comment: Ŝajnas ke la plej granda problemo kun "i" estas la pronomoj. Sen-tabelvorta teksto ne estas problemo, sed verkante la nunan tekston vere estas problemo la ne-uzo de la pronomoj.

Answer (score 3):

Laŭ mi eviti "A" estas plej malfacile, ĉar ĝi estas bezonata en la oftega vorto "la", en la oftega verbfinaĵo "-as", en ĉiuj adjektivoj, en oftegaj afiksoj kiel "mal-", "-ar-" kaj "-an-", kaj en multegaj aliaj vortoj. Sed ankaŭ evitado de "I" (pro pronomoj, tabelvortoj kaj infinitivoj) kaj "S" (pro ĉiu ne-infinitivaj, ne-imperativaj verboj) estas tre malfacila.

Comment: For sure it would be possible to write a passage of length without definite articles, verbs in present tense, adjectives, and compounds. I just did.

Comment: En kelkaj okazoj anstataŭ *la* eĉ eblus poeziece skribi *l’*.

Answer (score 1):

There were some well based answers here. So let's try it.

***Edit this answer and add ellided letters.***

- **a** - Ni evitis tiun homon pro nepovo redoni ties luon.
- **i** - Amanda estas damo loĝanta en la urbo de la rakontanto. Unu tagon Amanda ekvolas amuzan tempon en la teatro, laborejo de la rakontanto. La damo promenas al la bonvenejo kaj aĉetas permes-paperon por spektaklo nomata ”Estado aŭ ne estado, jen la demando”!
- **o** - Pluvas, neĝas kaj terure hajlas. Dumtage nenien ni ekskursas.
- **s** - For! Kuru kien la lumo ne montru.
- **s** - Ĉu vivi aŭ ne vivi – jen la demando: Ĉu pli noble elporti ĉiujn batojn, ĉiujn lancetojn de la kolera fortuno, aŭ armiĝi kontraŭ la tuta maro da mizeroj, kaj per la malcedo ilin fini?

Should give a feeling what style of text is possible. **a** is hard as it is a high frequency vowel too. With(out) **s** I would not come far.

Comment: :-) I don’t like changing other people’s answers, so here’s my try without **i**: *Amanda estas damo loĝanta en la urbo de la rakontanto. Unu tagon Amanda ekvolas amuzan tempon en la teatro, laborejo de la rakontanto. La damo promenas al la bonvenejo kaj aĉetas permes-paperon por spektaklo nomata ”Estado aŭ ne estado, jen la demando”!*

Comment: BTW, do infinitive-only texts exist in Esperanto? If this is permissible as a kind of ”artistic license”, writing a *looong* S-less text would be relatively easy: *Atendi ie en la lumo. Ĝui la kunecon. Vidi ŝin ordigante la florojn, la botelojn…*

Comment: Computer related menu items has a majority prefering infinitive **i** instead of **u**. But captions are not phrases, hence that probably does not count. Your examples fall in the somewhat same category:  `Ĝui la kunecon estus bone.` Or like a shopping list "buy fish, ..."

Comment: I see your point! :-) Those are not really full phrases. However, I do wonder, if an entire book was written like that – could it be an enjoyable experience for the reader? Yes, it would look like a long ”prose poem”, in a way. But if an ”infinitive story” is indeed an option, that would rule out S…

Comment: You may know the song **Ami**, by Valentina Cancino? It’s almost an ”infinitive text”: ***Ami estas** stari/Mano-en-mane/Antaŭ la vivo/Kune kun vi. //…manĝi/Ĉe sama tablo/La ĉiutagan panon/Kune kun vi.* Without ”*ami estas*”, yes, it would maybe read like a shopping list – but the relevant question is, I think: Would it work as a text? :-)    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=303M_aU1WIc&lc=z13ssnbqtyqygz3ln23hxfix3taxvx32z

Comment: Shakespeare’s famous ”To Be Or Not To Be” monologue also has a lot of infinitives. Maybe something like that could serve as an S-less Esperanto lipogram?

Comment: Here’s Zamenhof’s first part of ”2B or not 2B”:Ĉu esti aŭ ne esti,—tiel staras
Nun la demando: ĉu pli noble estas
Elporti ĉiujn batojn, ĉiujn sagojn
De la kolera sorto, aŭ sin armi
Kontraŭ la tuta maro da mizeroj
Kaj per la kontraŭstaro ilin fini?

Comment: I’ll try to reword it without S: **Ĉu vivi aŭ ne vivi – jen la demando: Ĉu pli noble elporti ĉiujn batojn, ĉiujn lancetojn de la kolera fortuno, aŭ armiĝi kontraŭ la tuta maro da mizeroj, kaj per la malcedo ilin fini?**